# Is it possible to overload a call to vars(object) in Python?

Tags: python, operator-overloading, variables

I have a class that overloads object attribute access by returning the attributes of its "row" attribute, along the following lines:

```
from collections import namedtuple
class MyObj(object):
    def __init__(self, y, z):
        r = namedtuple('row', 'a b')
        self.row = r(y, z)
        self.arbitrary = True
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.row, attr)
    def __dir__(self):
        return list(self.row._fields)

In [2]: m = MyObj(1, 2)
In [3]: dir(m)
Out[3]: ['a', 'b']
In [4]: m.a
Out[4]: 1
In [5]: vars(m)
Out[5]: {'arbitrary': True, 'row': row(a=1, b=2)}
In [6]: output = '{a} -> {b}'
In [7]: output.format(**vars(m.row))
Out[7]: '1 -> 2'
In [8]: output.format(**vars(m))
KeyError: 'a'
```

As I quite often do string formatting using vars() I'd like to be able to access *row's* attributes directly from the call to vars(). Is this possible?

---

*Edit following aaronsterling's answer*

The key to solving this, thanks to Aaron's pointer, is to check for `__dict__` in `__getattribute__`

```
from collections import namedtuple
class MyObj(object):
    def __init__(self, y, z):
        r = namedtuple('row', 'a b')
        self.row = r(y, z)
        self.arbitrary = True
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.row, attr)
    def __getattribute__(self, attribute):
        if attribute == '__dict__':
            return self.row._as_dict()
        else:
            return object.__getattribute__(self, attribute)
    def __dir__(self):
        return list(self.row._fields)

In [75]: m = MyObj(3, 4)

In [76]: m.a
Out[76]: 3

In [77]: vars(m)
Out[77]: OrderedDict([('a', 3), ('b', 4)])
```

Comment: @aaronasterling : yes, I should have mentioned that this is for Python 2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [docs](http://localhost/pythondocs/library/functions.html#vars) are so kind as to specify that `vars` works by returning the `__dict__` attribute of the object it's called on. Hence overriding `__getattribute__` does the trick. Y

I subclass `dict` (but see later) to override the `__str__` function. The subclass accepts a function `str_func` which gets called to return a string representation of how you want your `__dict__` object to appear. It does this by constructing a regular dictionary with the entries that you want and then calling `str` on that.

This is very hacky. In particular, it will break any code that depends on doing anything like

```
myobj.__dict__[foo] = bar
```

This code will now update a phantom dictionary and not the real one.

A much more robust solution would depend on completely replacing all methods that set values on the `SpoofedDict` with methods that actually update `myobj.__dict__`. This would require `SpoofedDict` instances to hold a reference to `myobj.__dict__`. Then of course, the methods that read values would have to fetch them out of `myobj.__dict__` as well.

At that point, you're better off using `collections.Mapping` to construct a custom class rather than subclassing from `dict`.

Here's the proof of concept code, hackish as it may be:

```
from collections import namedtuple


class SpoofDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.str_func = kwargs['str_func']
        del kwargs['str_func']

        dict.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.str_func()


class MyObj(object):
    def __init__(self, y, z):
        r = namedtuple('row', 'a b')
        self.row = r(y, z)
        self.arbitrary = True
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.row, attr)

    def __dir__(self):
        return list(self.row._fields)

    def str_func(self):
        attrs = list(self.row._fields)
        str_dict = {}
        row = object.__getattribute__(self, 'row')
        for attr in attrs:
            str_dict[attr] = getattr(row, attr)
        return str(str_dict)

    def __getattribute__(self, attribute):
        if attribute == '__dict__':
            spoof_dict = SpoofDict(str_func=self.str_func)
            spoof_dict.update(object.__getattribute__(self, '__dict__'))
            return spoof_dict                
        else:
            return object.__getattribute__(self, attribute)


if __name__=='__main__':
    m = MyObj(1, 2)
    print "dir(m) = {0}".format(dir(m))
    print "vars(m) = {0}".format(vars(m))
    print "m.row = {0}".format(m.row)
    print "m.arbitrary = {0}".format(m.arbitrary)
```

Comment: +1 for interesting analysis. BTW, the docs for Python 3.2 don't seem to promise that `__dict__` is used, so it might not be very safe.

Comment: @max Good looking out. This is probably a terrible idea. The asker would be better off just providing the class with a method to return the `dict` or string desired.

Answer (score 4):

You can also define a `@property` for `__dict__` instead of overriding `__getattribute__`.

```
class Example:
    @property
    def __dict__(self):
        return "From vars()"

e = Example()
print(vars(e)) # From vars()
```